# How to arrange handlebars partials in express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a working app in express. Right now I need to arrange partials (with hbs module). I have a layout set, navigation as well.

Layout.hbs contains elements as follow:

```
- {{>nav}}
- {{>body}}
- {{>footer}}
```

I am using {{> }} notation and it works. In footer section lies basic bootstrap scripts.

**Question:** What is missing, is that when I want to load a page which requires additional scripts at the bottom - I don't know how to chain it. How to add them in not in body section but in footer.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you think is missing ? Do you have an error in console ? Do you mean that the scripts that you add in the footer are not available for you ?

Comment: When I load a page that inherits layout, how can I add a additional script block that would be loaded in footer section instead of body?

Comment: Just modify your footer partial instead of the body. I must be missing something otherwise it seems obvious. Have you tried to modify your footer partial ?

Comment: What I was looking for is Inline block. Dynamically inject additional content into partials. Link to the great article in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the question was how to create dynamic layout(s) with the possibility to add partials and to expand them according to the page you are loading.

Short answer is to use inline blocks:

1.Somewhere in layout file you place:

```
{{#> scripts-block}}
  {{!-- Custom scripts per page could be added. --}}
{{/scripts-block}}
```

This block is optional so it won't throw an error in case it is missing.

2.Inside a page that is loaded in render():

```
{{#> layouts/layout }}
  {{#*inline "scripts-block"}}
    <script src="new-script.js"></script>
  {{/inline}}
{{/layouts/layout }}
```

Now it will work correctly.

Here is a great article with step by step tutorial on how to build it:

[power of handlebars](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/the-hidden-power-of-handlebars-partials/#fnref-4803-1)